Run the mysql migrations using Rust
I created a docker container that contains mysql using the command below,
docker container run --name mysql-831 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd -e MYSQL_SSL=false -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPYT_PASSWORD=true -e MYSQL_ALLOW_LOCAL_INFILE=true -p 3306:3306 -d mysql:latest

That's worked and I connected on DBeaver interface, but when I try to run the command diesel migration run with the DATABASE_URL value as DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@192.168.65.1:P@ssw0rd@localhost/mysql I had an error below,
Could not connect to database via `mysql://root@192.168.65.1:P@ssw0rd@localhost/mysql`: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

See the DBeaver edit connection image below,


What IP did you use for DBeaver?

Also doesn't that URL look wrong? root@192.168.65.1:P@ssw0rd@localhost - @192.168.65.1 and @localhost seem in conflict. Use localhost and connect using localhost:3306

Hi @Codebling I updated the post and I inserted an image about it, you can notice that I am using the 3306 port.

@Codebling if you said to try it DATABASE_URL=mysql://localhost:3306/mysql I did but it didn't work.

@Codebling I changed the password to DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/mysql and now I received the error Using unsupported buffer type: 253  (parameter: 1) when I tried to run diesel migration run

I found how to resolve it using the link https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/1bec9fc/error_using_unsupported_buffer_type_253_parameter/ and the issue https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/3929
I read about it can be a problem about My SQL version too and I followed these steps below to fix it.

Removed everything about mysql, to clean trash things.
brew uninstall mysql,brew uninstall mysql-client, brew uninstall mysql@<version>
brew install mysql@8.0 and brew install mysql-client@8.0
Locate your libmysqlclient, usually it is inside of /opt/homebrew/opt/mysql... or /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql...
Install the diesel_clie and MYSQLCLIENT_LIB_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql\@8.0/8.0.36/lib/ cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features=mysql --force 

About step 5, you need to change the MYSQLCLIENT_LIB_DIR using your libmysqlclient path.
